# How to make two rows navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, navbar, tailwind-css

I am making a react + tailwind app, where I am having requirement to implement the two row navbar one by one.

For which code that I have tried,

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <nav className="relative flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-2 py-3 bg-pink-500 mb-3">
        <div className="container px-4 mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
          <div className="w-full relative flex justify-between lg:w-auto lg:static lg:block lg:justify-start">
            <a
              className="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-white"
              href="#pablo"
            >
              Logo 1
            </a>
            <button
              className="text-white cursor-pointer text-xl leading-none px-3 py-1 border border-solid border-transparent rounded bg-transparent block lg:hidden outline-none focus:outline-none"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)}
            >
              <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            className={
              "lg:flex flex-grow items-center" +
              (navbarOpen ? " flex" : " hidden")
            }
            id="example-navbar-danger"
          >
            <ul className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none lg:ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 1 - Menu 1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2"> Row 1 - Menu 2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 1 - Menu 3</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            {/* Second row menus */}
            <ul className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none lg:ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 2 - Menu 1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2"> Row 2 - Menu 2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 2 - Menu 3</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a
            className="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-white"
            href="#pablo"
          >
            Logo 2
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I am a beginner to stackoverflow and so I don't know why the above snippet doesn't apply the respective styles but please go through complete working example here,

> [**https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-909d1**](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-909d1)

In the above example you could see that the first row menu and second row menu both are in same line, but I need to move the second row menu below first row.

Please kindly help me to achieve the result as like,

**Desktop View:**

```
| Logo 1   ------  Row-1-Menu-1 ---- Row-1-Menu-2 ---- Row-1-Menu-3 ----   Logo 2 |
|          ------  Row-2-Menu-1 ---- Row-2-Menu-2 ---- Row-2-Menu-3 ----          |
```

**Mobile/Tab View**

```
| Logo 1   --------- Logo 2 --- Hamburger Icon -- |
```

Current UI can be viewd here https://909d1.csb.app/

Comment: Hi and welcome on stackoverflow. Community will be happy to help you, but please follow the guidelines how to ask and especially how to provide "Minimal" reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
Also the `<Link ... />` is obviously not working here in code sample, so you can either include link to demo like you did, or even (much) better: write all the necessary (but minimal) css right here. My guess is that when you start to do this minimal example, you will find out the solution on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `flexDirection: column` to render your `ul` in one single column and need to remove `marginLeft: auto` from `ul`

Try something like below:-

```
import React from "react";

export default function Navbar({ fixed }) {
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="relative flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-2 py-3 bg-pink-500 mb-3">
        <div className="container px-4 mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
          <div className="w-full relative flex justify-between lg:w-auto lg:static lg:block lg:justify-start">
            <a
              className="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-white"
              href="#pablo"
            >
              Logo 1
            </a>
            <button
              className="text-white cursor-pointer text-xl leading-none px-3 py-1 border border-solid border-transparent rounded bg-transparent block lg:hidden outline-none focus:outline-none"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)}
            >
              <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            className={
              "lg:flex flex-grow items-center" +
              (navbarOpen ? " flex" : " hidden")
            }
            id="example-navbar-danger"
            style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}  // added flex direction
          >
            <ul className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none"> // removed margin left
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 1 - Menu 1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2"> Row 1 - Menu 2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 1 - Menu 3</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            {/* Second row menus */}
            <ul className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none"> // removed margin left
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 2 - Menu 1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2"> Row 2 - Menu 2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75"
                  href="#pablo"
                >
                  <span className="ml-2">Row 2 - Menu 3</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a
            className="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-white"
            href="#pablo"
          >
            Logo 2
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you of be any help here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67531195/15916627