# How to move navbar to right and apply background color?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am making a simple app using `react + tailwind` and I am currently working on navbar part.

**Navbar.js**:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Navbar({ fixed }) {
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="relative flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-2 py-3 bg-pink-500 mb-3">
        <div className="container px-4 mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
          <div className="w-full relative flex justify-between lg:w-auto lg:static lg:block lg:justify-start">
            <a
              className="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-white"
              href="#pablo"
            >
              Logo 1
            </a>
            <button
              className="text-white cursor-pointer text-xl leading-none px-3 py-1 border border-solid border-transparent rounded bg-transparent block lg:hidden outline-none focus:outline-none"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)}
            >
              <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            className={
              "lg:flex flex-grow items-center" +
              (navbarOpen ? " flex" : " hidden")
            }
            id="example-navbar-danger"
            style={{ flexDirection: "column" }} 
          >
            <ul className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75">
                  Row 1 - Menu 1
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75">
                  Row 1 - Menu 2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75">
                  Row 1 - Menu 3
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

**And complete working example here:**

> [**https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-1y10y**](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-1y10y)

Issue and things tried:

- In current scenario, the background-color pink is applied to the entire header layout.
- I can understand that this happens because I have applied the css classname `bg-pink-500` to the whole navbar.
- But if I move this background-color to any of the child div then it is not working as expected.

Requirement:

The requirement is that in responsive view, the whole layout needs to be exactly like this,

```
|  -- Logo --  This bar needs to have bg-pink  -- Hamburger Icon -- |
|                                                                   |
                                   |     -- Row 1 - Menu 1 --       |
                                   |     -- Row 1 - Menu 2 --       | --> Only this area have bg-pink
                                   |     -- Row 1 - Menu 3 --       |
                                   |     -- Row 2 - Menu 1 --       |
```

[**Please click on this image to see the similar expectation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NdOl.png)

Kindly please help me to achieve the `bg-pink` color only to the top navbar and the menu items bar to the right.

Current UI can be viewed in this link: https://1y10y.csb.app/ (Please switch to responsive mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `position` as `fixed` on your div which will be used as sidebar. But for other big screens you need to remove position property and it will show at middle of your nav bar.

Try something like below:-

```
import React from "react";

export default function Navbar({ fixed }) {
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="relative flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-2 py-3 bg-pink-500 mb-3">
        <div
          className="container px-4 mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between"
          style={{ position: "relative" }}
        >
          <div className="w-full relative flex justify-between lg:w-auto lg:static lg:block lg:justify-start">
            <a
              className="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-nowrap uppercase text-white"
              href="#pablo"
            >
              Logo 1
            </a>
            <button
              className="text-white cursor-pointer text-xl leading-none px-3 py-1 border border-solid border-transparent rounded bg-transparent block lg:hidden outline-none focus:outline-none"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)}
            >
              <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            className={
              "lg:flex flex-grow items-center" +
              (navbarOpen ? " flex" : " hidden")
            }
            id="example-navbar-danger"
            style={{
              flexDirection: "column",
              position: "fixed",
              right: 0,
              top: "41px",
              zIndex: 99999,
              background: "#ed64a6",
              height: "100%",
              minWidth: "200px"
            }} // added flex direction column because I will have another navbar below this.
          >
            <ul className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75">
                  Row 1 - Menu 1
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75">
                  Row 1 - Menu 2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="px-3 py-2 flex items-center text-xs uppercase font-bold leading-snug text-white hover:opacity-75">
                  Row 1 - Menu 3
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```